# Set of values such that no rows match condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table with column `uuid` and `type`. I want all the `uuid`'s `'xxxxx'` such that no rows have `uuid = 'xxxxx'` AND `type = 'buy'`.

This ends up the same as if you took all `uuid`'s in the table, and then removed all `uuid`'s that match `SELECT uuid FROM table WHERE type = 'buy'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a_uuid
from t
group by a_uuid
having not bool_or(type = 'Purchase')
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE

Comment: Is there a performance difference between this answer and Gordon's answer? (This is not premature optimization. This could be a big ol' query.)

Comment: @tscizzle: the best way to find out is to run an `explain` or `explain (analyze, verbose)` for those statements with _your_ data.

Comment: @tscizzle There could be a difference if there are many `a_uuid`s with many rows because `bool_or` stops searching at the first `true` value it finds while `sum` will read all rows regardless of if the sum is already bigger than 0.

Comment: that's short circuiting?

Answer (score 2):

I approach these problems using aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select a_uuid
from table t
group by a_uuid
having sum(case when type = 'Purchase' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

EDIT:

If you have a table with one row per `a_uuid`, then the fastest is likely to be:

```
select a_uuid
from adtbs a
where not exists (select 1 from table t where t.a_uuid = a.a_uuid and t.type = 'Purchase');
```

For this query, you want an index on `table(a_uuid, type)`.

Comment: Is there a performance difference between this answer and Clodoaldo's answer? (This is not premature optimization. This could be a big ol' query.)

Comment: @tscizzle . . . The performance difference would likely be very, very minor, given that the query has to incur the overhead of a `group by`.  The above is standard SQL; `bool_or()` is Postgres-specific.

Comment: @tscizzle . . . I don't know if the index would help in the first query.